# TestNG Assert showing error in selenium project

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

Assert is showing error even though testng is imported. error is **"Assert cannot be resolved"** and in the import of Assert the error is **"The import org.testng.Assert cannot be resolved"** .. Please help me to resolve this issue..

Answer (score 0):

This might be because the TestNG plugin is not installed on eclipse. Try to install the TestNG plugin, then this should get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you did not imported the correct testNG jar in your project. Just for reference , download it from [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/testng/testng/) .

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because you haven't added the TestNG in your project. Follow the below steps.

1. Right-click on any file/folder in the project in Eclipse.
2. Select Build Path -> Configure Build Path.
3. Select 'Libraries' tab.
4. Click on 'Add Library'.
5. Select TestNG. Click 'Ok'.

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Try this if another things don't work,Change the scope to compile instead of test.
It worked for me.

Comment: Please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.